# How to schedule a function to run every hour on Plumber?

Tags: r, asynchronous, cron, scheduled-tasks, plumber

I have a [Plumber](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plumber/index.html) web hosting with no access to cron command.

How can I execute some R function every day?

P.S. I'm aware of [cronR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cronR/index.html) package but this requires to have access to the cron command, in my setup in Azure Kubernetes, I can't run cron jobs

Comment: Host cron somewhere else that hits that endpoint. You don't need `cron` on the plumber-hosted instance to be able to do something with `cron`. Unfortunately, short of that there are hacks that _might_ recur a self-hit periodically but there's no guarantee it'll go, it will never "auto-start", and the server itself has motivation to not keep the process around more than it needs to. Frankly, having a cronjob (e.g., using `wget` or `curl`) elsewhere on the internet is the much simpler and more resilient way to go, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem here is that I want to run some R codes periodically in the Plumber server. But yes as you suggested I can expose an endpoint with that R job and call it periodically from somewhere else. Task schedule is a part of most of web servers providers and I guess plumber should have it too but I still didn't find the solution.

Comment: `plumber` has nothing to do with scheduling, and adding it to it is outside of its intent, adding unrelated complexity. I think I understand, though ... you have an administrative task (not currently addressed  directly by an endpoint) that you want run "in the background". My suggestion stands, yes you'll need to create a simple endpoint that spins off your daily task. When doing so, to guard against simultaneous execution, you may want a simple mutex/semaphore (e.g., using redis, database, or even just filesystem, though that is not guaranteed atomic).